# Javascript multiple slideshow

Tags: javascript

I have created an HTML file which uses java script to display images randomly displayed in 3 div tags. On click the images move left or right. It works fine until I use single slideshow in the page, but creates problem when I try multiple slideshows on the same page.

Here is the code for one slide show :

```
**<script>
currentIndx = 2;

MyImages=new Array();

MyImages[0]='1images2.jpeg';

MyImages[1]='1images3.jpeg';

MyImages[2]='1images4.jpeg';

MyImages[3]='artwork.jpg';

MyImages[4]='1images5.jpeg';

imagesPreloaded = new Array(4)

for (var i = 0; i < MyImages.length ; i++)

{
imagesPreloaded[i] = new Image(120,120)

imagesPreloaded[i].src=MyImages[i]
}

/* we create the functions to go forward and go back          */

function Nexter()

{

if (currentIndx<MyImages.length-1){
alert(currentIndx);
document.leftimg.src=document.middleimg.src
document.middleimg.src=document.rightimg.src
document.rightimg.src=imagesPreloaded[++currentIndx].src

}
else {
alert("In nexter else")
currentIndx=0
document.leftimg.src = document.middleimg.src

document.middleimg.src = document.rightimg.src

document.rightimg.src = imagesPreloaded[currentIndx].src

}

writeImageNumber();

}
function Backer()
{
if (currentIndx>0)
{

 --currentIndx; 

alert("In Backer If");

document.rightimg.src=document.middleimg.src

document.middleimg.src=document.leftimg.src

document.leftimg.src=imagesPreloaded[currentIndx].src

}

else 
{


  currentIndx = MyImages.length-1

  alert(MyImages.length +"else");

  document.rightimg.src = document.middleimg.src

  document.middleimg.src = document.leftimg.src

  document.leftimg.src = imagesPreloaded[currentIndx].src

}

writeImageNumber();

}

/*###### function to reload the images and text when refresh is pressed ##### */

function setCurrentIndex()
{
currentIndx=0;

document.theImage.src=MyImages[0];

document.form1.text1.value=Messages[0];

writeImageNumber();

}

</script>

<body onload="setCurrentIndex();automaticly()">

<!-- start of form for image slide show ####################### -->

<div id ="left" style="float:left"> 

<a href="#" onclick="Backer()" ><img src="1images2.jpeg" width="265" height="262" 
border="0" name="leftimg"></a>
</div>

<div id ="middle"  style="float:left">

<a href="#" onclick=""><img src="1images3.jpeg" width="265" height="262" 
 border="0"    name="middleimg"></a>
</div>

<div id ="right" class="compimg" style="float:left"> 
<a href="#" onclick="Nexter()" ><img src="1images4.jpeg"
width="265" height="262"  alt="" border="0"name="rightimg"></a>
</div> 

<!-- end of form for image slide show ####################### -->**



Any suggestions...
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't wrapped your script in any javascript class(object) so all variables you are using have global scope(page level). I guess your variables are over written if you try to use it multiple time.

You can get better answer if you post HTML markup of how you are trying to create multiple slideshow in single page...